# Error while installing WORKFOW MANAGER 1.0- CU2 - REFRESH on my SP 2013 SERVER SP1

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, workflow-manager

am getting BELOW error while installing the workflow manager 1.0 refresh (cu2) 
on my sharepoint server 2013  with service pack1 , on my win server 2012 r2 os.
can anyone please help what  am missing?
 do i need  to install all pre-requisites before installing WF MANAGER 1.0 CU2 - REFRESH ?
  [image: wfmanager-cu2-refresh-error]

Comment: What you select on previous screen? Also do you have internet connection on the server? Looks like unable to download the exe files.

Answer (score 1):

The source of the code @microsoft were unavailable a few seconds ago and returned the familiar `Server error in "/" Application`. I guess you're able to download if you try once more now.

Please note that you need to install Workflow Manager 1.0 before you can install cumulative updates.

[image]

The same goes for its Service Bus.

[image]

Comment: It was not service bus 1.0, its service bus 1.1 ,I was supposed to install. That solved my issue.